# Check if data exists across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am currently running this query inside MySQL to check if the specified values exists 
within the table associated with them.

```
SELECT COUNT(artist.artist_id), COUNT(album.album_id), COUNT(tracks.track_id) 
FROM artist, album, tracks WHERE artist.artist_id = 320295 OR album.album_id = 1234 OR tracks.track_id = 809
```

The result I get from running this query is all 1, meaning that all the statements after the WHERE clause is true. To further check the query's reliability, I changed the tracks.track_ = 809 to 802, which I know does not match. However the results displayed are still all 1, meaning that they were all successfully matched even when I purposefully inserted a value which would not have matched.

How do I get it to show 1 for a match and 0 for no matches within the same query?

EDIT: I have inserted an image of the query running

[image]

Comment: how are you getting the results? i think you may just be checking if the query worked.

Comment: I am getting the result in phpmyadmin and also running it through there.

Comment: You might want to read the documentation for [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count). I don't know what you are trying to do, but I don't think `COUNT` does what you think it does. It just counts all the non-NULL values. It does not check if a specific value exists or whatever it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do here is a join over three tables. You can see what happens, when you look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e913/7/0).

In the first select, I have left out the `count`, to show how the join works. You can also see how the result set changes, when you modify the where clause from `or` to `and` as @RayPaseur suggested.

I guess, what you want, is really three separate queries

```
select 'artist' as type, count(artist_id) as count
from artist
where artist_id = 320295
union
select 'album', count(album_id)
from album
where album_id = 1234
union
select 'track', count(track_id)
from tracks
where track_id = 809
```

which becomes

```
TYPE    COUNT
artist  1
album   1
track   1
```

Now, when you change `track_id = 809` to `track_id = 802`, you will get

```
TYPE    COUNT
artist  1
album   1
track   0
```

as a result.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e913/16/0) for playing.

Answer (score 0):

The "or" clause may be your issue here.  If any of those WHERE clauses works, you will have a results set that is not empty.  Maybe something like SELECT COUNT(*)... WHERE... AND... AND...

But it would be more helpful to see the entire PHP code set.  And I would recommend running three different queries - not because it's technologically sophisticated, but just because it is easier to get it to work right the first time!

Comment: Replacing the OR with AND gives makes all the results 0 since one of them is a mismatch.