# How to check if 'name' exist in multiple table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm willing to get result if all 'name' in table1 are exist in table2[multiple row with same name] and table3

already check these up:
1. [Check if data exists across multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906251/check-if-data-exists-across-multiple-tables)
2. [How to check if a given data exists in multiple tables (all of which has the same column)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232704/how-to-check-if-a-given-data-exists-in-multiple-tables-all-of-which-has-the-sam)

```
select idprov, (select a.provinsi from mst_province a where a.id_tbl_mst_prov = c.idprov ) as provinsi, namasite as namasite, count(namasite) as count from form_kuesioner_pengelola c 
union
select idprov, (select a.provinsi from mst_province a where a.id_tbl_mst_prov = c.idprov ) as provinsi, namasite as namasite, count(namasite) as count from form_kuesioner_manfaat c group by namasite 
union
select idprov, (select a.provinsi from mst_province a where a.id_tbl_mst_prov = c.idprov ) as provinsi, namalokasi as namasite, count(namalokasi) as count from form_kuesioner_surveyor c
```

So the result from code above get me all the 'name' that exist in table1 including the 'name' that not exist in other table.

And I want my result like

```
 table
    'name1' = 1 (exist) from form_kuesioner_pengelola  
    'name1' = 0 (not exist) from form_kuesioner_manfaat  
    'name1' = 0 (not exist) from form_kuesioner_surveyor
```

I know Im nowhere from 'near' can you enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: Sample data would really help.  I can't figure out what you are really trying to do.  Your problem statement sort of makes sense, but then you have a query and results and the three seem to h ave no relationship to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to get the names that exist in one table, but not the others:

```
select *
from form_kuesioner_pengelola p
where name = 'xyz'
  and not exists (select * from form_kuesioner_manfaat m where m.name = p.name)
  and not exists (select * from form_kuesioner_surveyor s where s.name = p.name)
order by name;
```

(If `name` is never null in `form_kuesioner_manfaat` and `form_kuesioner_surveyor`, you can even replace the `NOT EXISTS` clauses with simpler `NOT IN` clauses.)

UPDATE: Here is how to show in which tables the name is present.

```
select
  exists (select * from form_kuesioner_pengelola where name = 'xyz') as in_pengelola,
  exists (select * from form_kuesioner_manfaat where name = 'xyz') as in_manfaat,
  exists (select * from form_kuesioner_surveyor where name = 'xyz') as in_surveyor;
```

UPDATE: And here is a query that checks existence for all names in the tables. This is a bit clumnsy, because MySQL still doesn't support full outer joins.

```
select
  names.name,
  count(p.name) as in pengelola,
  count(m.name) as in in_manfaat,
  count(s.name) as in in_surveyor
from
(
    select name from form_kuesioner_pengelola
    union
    select name from form_kuesioner_manfaat
    union
    select name from form_kuesioner_surveyor
) names
left join form_kuesioner_pengelola p on p.name = names.name
left join form_kuesioner_manfaat m on m.name = names.name
left join form_kuesioner_surveyor s on s.name = names.name
group by names.name
group by names.name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Thorsten, but after i look my table again there was 'nama' that missing using this query.
is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, no. I simply answered the question how to find a name in one table and not in the others. I took your table names and a column named `name` for this. It is hard to tell what you want to do exactly. You say you look for a name in the three tables, but in your query there is suddenly a fourth table named `mst_province`. And you try to count something, but you don't do this properly. And you union rows, which doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question. So please show sample data and expected results, so we understand what you really want.

Comment: well sorry my bad. It has nothing to do with it ofc. My progress now that I already get datas from table that present in 3 table. With your query I already get rows that missing in table2 and table 3.
so my question is how do I make them into 1 query so that I can know this name present in which table? thx
*sorry my english bad

Comment: Okay, so you are not looking for a name that is present in one table and not in the others. You want to know in which of the tables a name is present or not. Do you want a query for one single name or for all names?

Comment: yes, and for all names. guide please. @thorsten.

Comment: Okay, I've added such query to my answer.

Comment: great help @Thorsten, thanks. Could you help me edit this question so its not on hold. May it come handy for other.